# OSX: Quit application propertly - shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I often need to quit some application, the standard way is for example:
Chrome -> Quit Google Chrome

However, since I like keyboard, I prefer shortcuts. For most applications, cmd Q works fine, but there are some apps that do not close properly on such an action (do not get notified about quiting, almost like they got a kill signal instead of a shutdown one, then they do not save files in the database, leave configs corrupted, etc.). Is there a shortcut on OSX that would be equivalent to going to Application Name -> Close Application Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a key sequence to properly close an application, then that sequence should appear next to "Close Application" or "Quit" in the application's File menu.  If that sequence does not in fact cleanly shut down the application, then the application is broken and you should be filing a bug report with the developer.

Comment: I contacted the software company and they confirmed I found a bug.